# Multiple file upload with image preview

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I've a multiple file upload form and I need to display the real time preview of uploaded images. I've implemented this by using jQuery. But from that preview images, I want to select the default image ( a radio button along with images to select ).

```
<input type="file" name="pictures[]" multiple="multiple" id="fileupload" />

<div id="dvPreview"></div>
```

JQuery code to display the file preview;

```
$("#fileupload").change(function () {
    if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
        var dvPreview = $("#dvPreview");
        dvPreview.html("");
        var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.jpg|.jpeg|.gif|.png|.bmp)$/;
        $($(this)[0].files).each(function () {
            var file = $(this);
            if (regex.test(file[0].name.toLowerCase())) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    var img = $("<img />");
                    img.attr("style", "width:150px; height:100px; margin-right: 10px;margin-top: 10px;");
                    img.attr("src", e.target.result);
                    dvPreview.append(img);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(file[0]);
            } else {
                alert(file[0].name + " is not a valid image file.");
                dvPreview.html("");
                return false;
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert("This browser does not support HTML5 FileReader.");
    }
});
```

But I need to place a radio button along with this to select the default image.

Now I can see the post values like this;

```
array =>
      0 => array
         name => 'image-1.jpg'
         type => 'image/jpeg'
         tmp_name => '/opt/lampp/temp/phpoktbaw'
         error => 0
         size => 706557
      1 => array
         name => 'image-2.jpg'
         type => 'image/jpeg'
         tmp_name => '/opt/lampp/temp/phpl4rbsi'
         error => 0
         size => 1785309
      2 => array
         name => 'image-3.jpg'
         type => 'image/jpeg'
         tmp_name => '/opt/lampp/temp/phpn72EL4'
         error => 0
         size => 104845
```

If possible I need to add one more variable to this array with the selected default image value.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
<input type="hidden" name="active[]" value="0" class="active" />
<input type="radio" name="activeImage[]" onclick="$('.active').val(0);$(this).prev().val(1)" value="1" />
```

Hope this helps....

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [link](http://www.codexworld.com/upload-multiple-images-using-jquery-ajax-php/). Hope this helps.

**EDIT:**

For selecting default image:

```
<?php
if(!empty($images_arr)){ 
    foreach($images_arr as $image_src){ ?>
        <ul>
            <li >
                <img src="<?php echo $image_src; ?>" alt="">
            </li>
        </ul>
<?php }
}
?>
```

In this code, below image tag there should be hidden radio button and on image click radio button below selected image will be checked. This can be done using javascript function. Set checkbox value to image url.

On click change border of image so that use will know the image is selected.

Comment: Yes. This is good. But I need an option to select the default image.

Comment: I can tell you way to do in code on link I share. Is it ok with you?

Comment: ya ok fine. Then I'll follow that link.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I proceed?

Comment: Yes, I understand your idea. But when we submit the form, do we get this value in post?

Comment: Yes. Give name to radio button and Just make sure this code will included between your form tag. Set checkbox value to image url.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95565/discussion-between-arun-chandran-and-apb).

Answer (score 0):

multiple image upload & preview using php

```html
<?php 
// database constants
define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASS", "");
define("DB_NAME", "demo3");
?>
?php


 // Create a database connection
 $connection = @mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
 if (!$connection) {
  die("database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
 }
 // Select a database to use
 $db_select = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$connection);
 if (!$db_select) {
  die("database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
 }
 ?>

<?php
//product id enter
$product_id='phoneas';
$x=1;
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
    $errors= array();
 foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
  $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
  $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
  $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
  $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key]; 
        if($file_size > 2097152){
   $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
        }  
        
        $photo_id=time()+$x;
        $x=$x+1;
        $query="INSERT INTO `photo`(`P_ID`, `PHOTO_ID`, `PHOTO_NAME`) VALUES ('$product_id','$photo_id','$file_name')";
        $desired_dir="uploads/".$product_id;
        if(empty($errors)==true){
            if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
                mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);  // Create directory if it does not exist
            }
            if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$file_name);
            }else{         // rename the file if another one exist
                $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
                 rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;    
            }
   mysql_query($query);   
        }else{
                print_r($errors);
        }
    }
 if(empty($error)){
  echo "Success";
 }
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<style type="text/css">
.thumbimage {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    position:relative;
    padding:5px;
}
</style>
<div id="wrapper">
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input id="imageupload"  type="file" name="files[]" multiple/>
 <input type="submit"/>
</form>
<div id="preview-image"></div>
</div>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
 $("#imageupload").on('change', function () {
 
     var countFiles = $(this)[0].files.length;
 
     var imgPath = $(this)[0].value;
     var extn = imgPath.substring(imgPath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
     var image_holder = $("#preview-image");
     image_holder.empty();
 
     if (extn == "gif" || extn == "png" || extn == "jpg" || extn == "jpeg") {
         if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
 
             for (var i = 0; i < countFiles; i++) {
 
                 var reader = new FileReader();
                 reader.onload = function (e) {
                     $("<img />", {
                         "src": e.target.result,
                             "class": "thumbimage"
                     }).appendTo(image_holder);
                 }
 
                 image_holder.show();
                 reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[i]);
             }
 
         } else {
             alert("It doesn't supports");
         }
     } else {
         alert("Select Only images");
     }
 });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Give explanations of what changes you have done and why?